# Sql Server - How to sort other than alphanumeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Sql Server 2008 I have a DB table, and the data includes a field that indicates a time period in the form: 2d, 1w, 4y, where "d" = day, "w" = week, "y" = year.  What is the best way to sort based on this field so that they are in time order (e.g. "3w" before "1y")?

Thanks

Comment: a wise person once told me to only store one piece of info per column.  you are storing multiple in this column, which is what is causing you problems.  The best solution is to store the data differently: possibly 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're lucky that d is before w and w is also before y so you could do

`ORDER BY RIGHT(MyField, 1), CONVERT(int, LEFT(Field, LEN(Field) - 1))`

However this is not going to put 1w before 8d for example.

So an alternative (more complicated) solution could be

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE RIGHT(Field, 1)
       WHEN 'd' THEN LEFT(Field, LEN(Field) - 1)
       WHEN 'w' THEN 7*LEFT(Field, LEN(Field) - 1)
       ELSE 356 * LEFT(Field, LEN(Field) - 1)
   END
```

It makes assumptions about your data (e.g. only d, w, and y are going to be there) and doesn't take account of leap years (if that matters).

Comment: 2d is smaller than 5d - in your example this will not be correctly handled.

Comment: @Parkyprg: Sure it would. Did you not see the second sort field?

Comment: @Ray: You don't know for sure what can be there. For example 2d would come after 10d as it is a string.

Comment: You're for your second example, you could convert the left part of the string to a number. But then you'd need to use the second solution anyway to make 10d bigger than 1w.

Comment: @Parkyprg fixed the first solution as per your test case.

Comment: That's why I used in my answer the idea of having another table for sorting purposes. In this way in the future, this can be extended to other needs as well.

Comment: I agree your way is better if you can modify the schema, if you're stuck and you can't, at least this would work.

Answer (score 2):

You may have different periods over time. So i would put this periods in a new table with ID, time period and sort order (or no. of days). In the initial table replace the field with time_period_id and make a join in your query and use it in SORT BY.

Comment: This is the proper solution if you're able to modify the schema.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your characters with string numbers and convert to integer before sorting, Like:

```
convert(int, replace(replace(replace(myField,'d',''),'w','0')'y','00'))
```

So your 3d is 3, 2w is 20 and 4y is 400.

---

after thinking about a bit, it's gonna better to calculate the real values through a case expression. e.g. to get 14 for 2w which is less than 13d.

Comment: You might want to make y 000 otherwise 40w is 400 which is bigger than 1y=100.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So it's better to calculate the real timespan.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to write a function that parses your duration string and normalizes it in the smallest possible units that can be expressed (I'm assuming that it's days, but if you can have hours or some smaller unit expressed, use that).  Then, have a computed column that is the value of that function called against your column.  At that point, it's just a matter of comparing the numbers.  Of course, the devil's in the details...  I don't relish trying to parse text from T-SQL though.